# How to use threads in PHP 7.0.20 in XAMPP?

Tags: php, multithreading, xampp

How to use threads in PHP 7.0.20 in XAMPP 32bit VLC 14? Using php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x86 and it gives me errors.

Comment: What do you mean "driver"? Also you should actually tag your question with `PHP` if this is related to PHP. Also list any errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

PHP threads can only be used in the CLI SAPI (that is, for command-line scripts). They cannot be used in a web server environment, as they are incompatible with the web server's existing use of threads.

[As I've mentioned elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44770376/149341), the PHP pthreads extension is a half-hearted attempt to introduce threading to a language which was never designed to support it. The extension is heavily limited, awkward to use, and slow. Avoid it.